# Aggregation sum in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to sum two fields from a Mongo collection; the fields can be a string, a number or not exist; this two strategies in an aggregation pipeline seems not to work (I receive always zero value as a Int32)
First strategy:

```
"field1": {
                            $sum: {
                                $add: [
                                    {
                                        $toInt: {
                                            $ifNull: [
                                                "$field2",
                                                0
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        $toInt: {
                                            $ifNull: [
                                                "$field3",
                                                0
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
```

Second strategy:

```
"field4": {
                            $sum: {
                                $add: [
                                    {
                                        $convert: {
                                            input: {
                                                $ifNull: [
                                                    "$field5",
                                                    0
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            to: "int",
                                            onError: 0,
                                            onNull: 0
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        $convert: {
                                            input: {
                                                $ifNull: [
                                                    "$field6",
                                                    0
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            to: "int",
                                            onError: 0,
                                            onNull: 0
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
```

Comment: Use `{$match: {$expr: { $isNumber: "$field5" }}}` or `{$match:{ field5: { $type: [ "double", "int", "long", "decimal" ] } } }`

Comment: Can you show us some of your documents and expected results?